# WPF: how to make a path's size conform to its parent's size

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Let's say in blend I take the pen tool and I just create a closed shape.

I'd like to then make this shape's width (or height) stretch to its container's dimensions.

So let's say I have

```
<Grid Width="500">
    <Path Data="Bla Bla" Width="200">
</Grid>
```

In other words, how can I make the path's width conform to its parent. I try to just go

```
<Canvas Width="500">
    <Path Data="Bla Bla" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
</Canvas>
```

but that doesn't work. it works with a rectangle but not with a path, so how can I do it with a path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<Viewbox>
    <Path .../>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: viewbox is almost good, except it makes my path conform to both width AND height of the parent. how can I make it conform to just the width dimension but leave the height alone?

Comment: I found it, <Viewbox Stretch="Fill">

Comment: <Viewbox Stretch="Fill"> will only work if you path doesn't have negative points. In this case set Stretch="Fill" on the path itself.