# WPF user control within user control not rendering path

Tags: wpf

I have a toolbox which is a user control, which has a grid control inside it. Each grid cell is populated by another set of user controls representing each tool. Now each tool has a path with gradient fill representing an icon. The tool user control looks fine in the designer, but when I load the tool into the toolbox nothing shows up. I tried changing the background of the tool and it is reflected in the toolbox. So for some reason the path with the gradient will is not rendered when loaded within another control. Any ideas why?

toolbar

```
<usercontrol ...> 
        <local:SettingsButton/>
</usercontrol>
```

toolbox (SettingsButton)

```
<usercontrol ...> 
        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="AliceBlue">
        <Path Data="M152.76824,152 ... />
        <Path.Fill>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop.../>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Path.Fill>
        </Grid>
</usercontrol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the control inside a viewbox or else the path wont re-size itself. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108548/wpf-how-to-make-a-paths-size-conform-to-its-parents-size) helped me.